# Python parsing txt, cut specific part of the string between two characters

Tags: python, string, parsing

I am trying make a script that will cut specific part of the string from loaded file.

For example string in file is (there are multiple lines like this and on all of them same should be done):

```
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file.h
```

Wanted output would be:

```
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4
```

So in each line only path to the folder should stay, without file itself.

What would be best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to remove all `*.h` from the paths?

Comment: Yes, so I have to load all files from one folder, and in each of them do this kind of modification for all lines (which are paths with filename), and I only need a path without filename, after that I will remove duplicate paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So since I did not explained well my question at first (did it in comments after), I had to work this out and finally this piece of code does the job:

```
for file in directory:
    f = open(file,'r')
    rows = f.readlines()
    array = []
    for i in rows:
        if i.endswith('.h\n'):
            array.append(i.replace(os.path.basename(i), ''))
    wf = open(file,'w')
    for row in array:
        wf.write(row+'\n')
    wf.close()
```

So it will go through all files inside of a folder and from this:
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1\file3.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2\file5.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3\file3.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4\file4.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5\file2.h

make this:

C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5

Hopefully it will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Why not [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp) using an escaped `\` like this and join all but the final filename item.  If you require the filename for other purposes then split() and just use the index -1 to get that part.

Note I have added an r in front of the string so all backslashes are left unchanged.  You can read about this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

```
my_file_location = r"C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file.h"

print('\\'.join(my_file_location.split('\\')[0:-1])) # path
>> C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4

print(my_file_location.split('\\')[-1]) # filename
>> file.h
```

If you want to iterate over a list of these filenames then you could do something like this:

```
import csv

output_list = []
with open('my_csv_example.csv', 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in csv_reader:
        output_list.append('\\'.join(row[0].split('\\')[0:-1]))

with open('my_csv_output_example.csv', mode='w') as f2:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f2, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in output_list:
        csv_writer.writerow([row])
```

Input File (my_csv_example.csv):

```
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1\file3.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2\file5.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3\file3.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4\file4.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5\file2.h
```

Output File (my_csv_output_example.csv):

```
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5
```

Updating due to comment, I think the bit you are missing is trying to run a string function on a list.  You need likely need the first element in the list i.e. 0 so this is the key bit for you:

```
row[0].split('\\')[0:-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for this assistance!

Comment: So I have file called file.d, contains lot of similar lines which all of them are paths just like one from the example, I can use this same way in here? I basically want to load file, modify it with removing filename and save that same file with just path.

Comment: For now I have this code which loads the all files from folder and replaces frontslashes to backslashes: for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r')
    change_file = open_file.read()
    change_file = change_file.replace('/', '\\')
    change_file = change_file.replace(' \\', '')
    write_file = open(file,'w')
    write_file.write(change_file)
    write_file.close()

Comment: That sounds like a second question.  It's difficult to read a comment so take what you don't know from this one and create a new one referencing this one for context.  This one should be marked correct IF it provides an answer to the specific question you asked.

Comment: Problem with your solution is that I have no my_file_location defined, I need to call readlines() from my file in order to get one by one line that I have to modify. And list object has no attribute split.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, hence why a specific question would be helpful.  I have updated with slightly more of an example.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: I am trying to load file which has extension .d, so these csv libraries won't work

Comment: The file extension of a file makes no bearing on whether CSV can read the file or not.  If you have a file in a specific format you will need to ask a further question explaining the format of the file.  It's out of scope of this question which already has 2 perfectly acceptable answers.

Comment: I can agree with that, will post new question with more detailed description, thanks

Comment: This question should be marked as correct if it answers your initial question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) for extensive and cross platform path support.

In your particular example:

```
from pathlib import PureWindowsPath

p=PureWindowsPath(r'C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file.h')
```

Then you can access the parts at will:

```
>>> p.name
file.h
>>> p.parents[0]
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4
>>> p.parents[1]
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3
# etc
```

You can change the type of path:

```
>>> p.as_uri()
file:///C:/d/projects/project1/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/file.h
>>> p.as_posix()
C:/d/projects/project1/folder1/folder2/folder3/folder4/file.h
```

Pathlib also has built-in support for globbing.

Given a file tree like this:

```
.
├── a
│   └── sub_a
│       └── sub_sub_a
│           └── file.txt
├── b
│   └── sub_b
│       └── file2.txt
└── c
    └── file3.txt
```

You can do:

```
for pn in (n for n in p.glob('**/*') if n.is_file()):
    print(pn)
```

Prints:

```
/tmp/test/a/sub_a/sub_sub_a/file.txt
/tmp/test/c/file3.txt
/tmp/test/b/sub_b/file2.txt
```

Which can be the path of any path that contains a file:

```
for pn in (n for n in p.glob('**/*') if n.is_file()):
    print(pn.parents[0])

/tmp/test/a/sub_a/sub_sub_a
/tmp/test/c
/tmp/test/b/sub_b
```

It is definitely a superior approach.

Comment: Seems like a fine solution, but in my case, I need to load all of the files with extention .d from one specific folder, and then in each file replace lines: C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1\file3.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2\file5.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3\file3.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4\file4.h
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5\file2.h

Comment: @John: Just change the glob or the path then. It does not need to be recursive. You can also use pathlib to rename the files or move the files which appears what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a perfect situation for [`str.rfind()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind).  It finds the right-most index of a given substring, in this case `\`.

```
list = [C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1\file3.h, 
        C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2\file5.h, 
        C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3\file3.h, 
        C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4\file4.h, 
        C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5\file2.h]
for line in list:
    line = line[ 0 : line.rfind("\\") ]
    print(f"{line}\n")
```

Output:

```
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder5\folder1
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder4\folder2
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder3
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder2\folder4
C:\d\projects\project1\folder1\folder2\folder1\folder5
```